# How to display large amount of data (~8Mb) on a web browser at once?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I have to display around 8Mb of data on a web browser. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use pagination. Currently my chrome, FF, IE hang while rendering this huge data.

Is there any way to tweak the browser or domain storage or cache settings to handle large amount of data ?